# Renamed PC and WinForm Dataset wont talk to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, dataset

i renamed my pc. i have a winforms app that used a database.  when i try to run the program, it crashes saying it cant find the db.  i understand the problem, dont know how to fix it.

so my connection string in the app config file looks like this:
"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"

when i try to configure the dataset with the configuration wizard, i see the string as
"Data Source=oldpcname\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"

but i cannot edit that string.  and adding my new pc name to the app config connection string so it looks like the connection string that the dataset is using... well that doesnt fix it.

i feel like this should be a lot easier than it is.  should i just delete the dataset entirely and try to recreate it?  thats a lot of work that seems unnecessary

Comment: Is your computer on a domain ?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the DataSet from the Solution Explorer and create a new one.  As long as all the table and column names are the same, any code that uses the DataSet will just work.

Comment: i added some custom select statements that help fill controls on the form.  thats why i feel like it will be a lot of work to recreate it

Comment: That does make it a pain, yes.  I would have thought that just using .\SQLEXPRESS would work.  You could perhaps try (local)\SQLEXPRESS but I'm not sure that that would work any differently.  I've never been in your shoes so I'm not sure what's going on under the hood there.